КузнечиК - задача
Перед клетчатой полоской длины n сидит кузнечиК. В каждой клетке написано какое-то число. КузнечиК умеет прыгать на 1,2,… k клеток вперед. Необходимо попасть в самую правую клетку, набрав при этом минимально возможную сумму. На вход подается n, k, и n значений клеток.
Не могу понять, как решить задачу оптимальным способом. Пока я думаю лишь о работе с деком, добавляя новое значение после каждой новой клетки и, если надо, удаляя старую. Но, получается, каждый раз я должен искать новый минимум в деке. Есть ли боле оптимальный вариант?

"На вход подается n, k, и n " --- почему два раза n? если это ошибка, то что значит первая n? В итоге пока не ясно, кузнечик может прыгать на любое значение от 1 до k или как

Есть ощущение, что если количество клеток больше, чем k, то всё сводится к тому, чтобы поделить n/k  и целое число будет означать количество раз надо прыгнуть k прыжков, а остаток - это последний прыжок

@АлексейШиманский на вход подаётся n, k и (n чисел которые написаны в клетках). Надо минимизировать  сумму чисел в посещённых кузнечиком клетках. Например 5, 2, 10 1 1 10 1.

@AlexeyTen ааааа. понял

Стандартная задача на динамическое программирование

должен искать новый минимум в деке — можно дополнительно хранить отсортированный дек. Как обычно меняем время на память.

Работа с деком: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164901/291659  и https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195098/844416

human-like решение: разбить маршрут на цели\учаски

За O(n*k) пишется в два вложенных цикла.

1. Очередь на двух стеках
Очередь с поддержкой минимума построена на двух стеках с поддержкой минимума.
# очередь, которая умеет возвращать минимум всех элементов в ней
class MinQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._s1 = []     # первый стек хранит только значения без минимумов
        self._s1_min = [] # текущий минимум всего первого стека
        self._s2 = []     # второй стек хранит только минимумы без значений

    # константа
    def len(self):
        return len(self._s1) + len(self._s2)

    # константа
    def min(self, default=None):
        # минимум по обоим стекам
        return min(self._s1_min + self._s2[-1:], default=default)

    # константа
    def push(self, v):
        self._s1.append(v)                       # добавить в первый стек
        self._s1_min = [min([v] + self._s1_min)] # обновить минимум первого стека

    # амортизированная константа
    def pop(self):
        if not self._s2: # если второй стек пуст
            while self._s1: # пока первый стек не пуст
                # положить во второй стек новый минимум
                self._s2.append(min([self._s1.pop()] + self._s2[-1:]))
            self._s1_min = [] # стереть минимум первого стека
        self._s2.pop()


# последовательное чтение целых чисел из входного потока
def ints():
    while True:
        yield from map(int, input().split())


def main():
    it = ints()

    n = next(it) # число клеток в полоске
    k = next(it) # максимальная длина прыжка

    # содержит минимальные суммы для последовательных клеток
    q = MinQueue()
    for _ in range(n):
        v = q.min(default=0) + next(it) # сердце алгоритма
        if q.len() >= k:
            q.pop()
        q.push(v)

    print(v) # печать последнего элемента очереди


main()

2. Упорядоченная по возрастанию очередь
Идея заимствована из ответа MBo. Обычный deque, но новые элементы удаляют из конца очереди элементы больше либо равные им. Понятно, что эти большие элементы повлиять на минимум в будущем не смогут. Такая очередь упорядочена по возрастанию в каждый момент времени.
import collections


# очередь, которая умеет возвращать минимум всех элементов в ней
class MinQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._i = 0 # индекс хвоста очереди
        self._q = collections.deque() # (индекс, значение), значения возрастают

    # константа
    def len(self):
        return self._i - self._q[0][0] if self._q else 0

    # константа
    def min(self, default=None):
        return self._q[0][1] if self._q else default

    # амортизированная константа
    def push(self, v):
        while self._q and self._q[-1][1] >= v:
            self._q.pop()
        self._q.append((self._i, v))
        self._i += 1

    # константа
    def pop(self):
        self._q.popleft()

Сравнение
Обе очереди обеспечивают линейную сложность решения задачи. У какой лучше константа?
В таблице через дробь записаны времена для "двух стеков" и "упорядоченной очереди". Упорядоченная очередь мало замечает изменение k – на случайных данных эта очередь короткая. "Два стека" всегда хуже. Иногда в два раза, иногда больше.




n=105
n=106
n=107




k=100
0.24 / 0.13
2.62 / 1.64
26.98 / 17.05


k=101
0.23 / 0.12
2.27 / 1.22
23.77 / 13.66


k=102
0.21 / 0.12
2.14 / 1.17
22.32 / 12.00


k=103
0.21 / 0.12
2.15 / 1.19
22.62 / 11.86


k=104
0.22 / 0.12
2.39 / 1.19
35.37 / 12.31


k=105
0.18 / 0.12
2.39 / 1.21
36.00 / 11.92


k=106

2.02 / 1.25
41.26 / 12.30


k=107


49.78 / 12.04



Восстановление маршрута
Если к элементам очереди добавить маршрут (список индексов), его можно будет восстановить:
def main():
    it = ints()

    n = next(it) # число клеток в полоске
    k = next(it) # максимальная длина прыжка

    # содержит пары (минимальная сумма, маршрут) для последовательных клеток
    q = MinQueue()
    for i in range(n):
        v, r = q.min(default=(0, None))
        if q.len() >= k:
            q.pop()
        v += next(it) # сердце алгоритма
        r = i, r
        q.push((v, r))

    print(v, r) # печать последнего элемента очереди


Спасибо, действительно работает. Но можете ли вы показать, как сделать восстановление ответа. У меня пока не получается реализовать

@НикитаБауэр, сделал хранение маршрута.

Что-то сложно... Какая асимптотика? За O(n*k) двумя циклами пишется. UPDATE: Судя по замерам, у тебя сильно лучше асимптотика. Деревом отрезков могу сделать O(n*lb(k)) (а может и лучше), наверное...

@Qwertiy O(n), не зависит от k

@MBo, хм.. а как 26 превращается в 49 в последнем столбце таблицы в зависимости от k?

@Qwertiy, утилизация кеша процессора падает? "Два стека" хранит два стека размером k. Перекачать два стека по десять миллионов элементов - не фунт изюма. Тем не менее, сложность O(n), от k не зависит.
